# Has anyone used Semantics3 api with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Has anyone successfully used this API?  Trying to build a price compare feature and having trouble parsing the json data into a rails data structure.  I am trying to filter the results to just the seller and lastest offered price.  anyone have a solution?

my controller

```
sem3.products_field("search", "green toys tractor")
sem3.products_field( "sitedetails", "name")


# Make the query

@productsHash = sem3.get_products()
```

and in the view

```
<%= @productsHash %>
```

I am able to see the entire json hash and I tried parsing it with the json gem.

```
JSON.parse(@productsHash)
```

but wondering if someone has some example code of their own they could share.

my results

{"total_results_count"=>9189, "code"=>"OK", "offset"=>0, "results_count"=>10, "results"=>[{"cat_id"=>"20823", "ean"=>"0649241988953", "model"=>"UMB13 A1342 GREEN", "offers_total"=>19, "weight"=>"340194.28", "category"=>"Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories", "name"=>"Green mCoverÂ® Hard Shell Cover Case + Free Keyboard Skin for A1342 White Unibody MacBook 13-inch", "updated_at"=>1387963145, "width"=>"335.28", "upc"=>"649241988953", "brand"=>"Green", "created_at"=>1347717401, "color"=>"Green", "sem3_id"=>"1jAjbOWuXQmWG0wMwGg46m", "features"=>{"Product Dimensions"=>"9.2 x 13.2 x 1.1 inches ; 12 ounces"}, "height"=>"27.94", "length"=>"233.68", "manufacturer"=>"iPearl Inc, USA", "gtins"=>["00649241988953"], "geo"=>["usa"], "price_currency"=>"USD", "price"=>"17.80", "sem3_help"=>"To view image links and additional merchants for this product, please upgrade your plan."}, {"cat_id"=>"20823", "ean"=>"0649241988403", "model"=>"ALU MB GREEN", "offers_total"=>25, "weight"=>"285763.19", "category"=>"Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories", "name"=>"GREEN mCover Hard Shell Case for 13-inch aluminum A1278 MacBook Pro (13.3-inch diagonal screen)", "updated_at"=>1387817680, "price"=>"13.99", "width"=>"28.45", "upc"=>"649241988403", "brand"=>"Green", "created_at"=>1347554377, "sem3_id"=>"6VQYSLooueo2ks0WUqIec2", "features"=>{"Product Dimensions"=>"13 x 1.1 x 9.1 inches ; 10.1 ounces"}, "mpn"=>"ALU-MB-GREEN", "height"=>"231.65", "length"=>"330.20", "manufacturer"=>"iPearl Inc, USA", "gtins"=>["00649241988403"], "geo"=>["usa"], "price_currency"=>"USD", "sem3_help"=>"To view image links and additional merchants for this product, please upgrade your plan."}, {"cat_id"=>"20823", "ean"=>"0872621001632", "model"=>"RT SPM14X02", "offers_total"=>509, "weight"=>"158757.33", "category"=>"Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories", "name"=>"Green Onion Supply RT-SPM14X02 Ag2 Anti-glare Screen Protectoraccs For Dell Alienware M14x", "updated_at"=>1388313241, "price"=>"28.87", "upc"=>"872621001632", "brand"=>"Green", "sem3_id"=>"2c8IsQrCnMq8KgEgiMo6yW", "created_at"=>1347808883, "features"=>{"Package Content"=>"MicroFiber cloth", "Display Screen Size Compatibility"=>"14\" wide", "Other Features"=>"Anti-glare, anti-scratch, reusable", "Product Type"=>"Notebook screen protector"}, "mpn"=>"RT-SPM14X02", "sitedetails"=>[{"sku"=>"17046069", "latestoffers"=>[{"seller"=>"Walmart", "lastrecorded_at"=>1387704200, "firstrecorded_at"=>1379990800, "currency"=>"USD", "availability"=>"In stock", "price"=>"32.24", "id"=>"5pPydRLcRcUIIeu8iG4o4K"}, {"seller"=>"Walmart", "lastrecorded_at"=>1360662000, "firstrecorded_at"=>1360662000, "currency"=>"USD", "availability"=>"In stock", "id"=>"7Yf1biLaZkMcSwOyKUuS4m", "price"=>"31.24"}, {"seller"=>"Walmart", "lastrecorded_at"=>1358731800, "firstrecorded_at"=>1358731800, "currency"=>"USD", "availability"=>"In stock", "id"=>"51zIYD0tYeSECu4KGuKC2s", "price"=>"30.93"}], "name"=>"walmart.com", "offers_count"=>20, "url"=>"http://www.walmart.com/ip/17046069", "recentoffers_count"=>1}, {"offers_count"=>3, "sku"=>"1092214", "latestoffers"=>[{"seller"=>"NextWarehouse.com", "lastrecorded_at"=>1384661400, "currency"=>"USD", "firstrecorded_at"=>1384661400, "availability"=>"Available", "id"=>"0QuY3kcCdagYaUeGwYyS2o", "price"=>"35.95"}, {"seller"=>"NextWarehouse.com", "lastrecorded_at"=>1382359600, "currency"=>"USD", "firstrecorded_at"=>1382359600, "availability"=>"Available", "price"=>"36.13", "id"=>"2SLt8pdveGqGUUaAWW0w62"}, {"seller"=>"NextWarehouse.com", "lastrecorded_at"=>1379825800, "firstrecorded_at"=>1379825800, "currency"=>"USD", "availability"=>"Available", "id"=>"7eJC9XuXVuQ8GWSqWCIqKq", "price"=>"35.95"}], "url"=>"http://www.nextwarehouse.com/item/?1092214_g10e", "name"=>"nextwarehouse.com", "recentoffers_count"=>1}, {"offers_count"=>3, "sku"=>"1604730", "latestoffers"=>[{"seller"=>"Colamco", "lastrecorded_at"=>1384661400, "currency"=>"USD", "firstrecorded_at"=>1384661400, "availability"=>"Available", "id"=>"1ZNuX5bmpY4mACsIOqIg8K", "price"=>"36.27"}, {"seller"=>"Colamco", "lastrecorded_at"=>1382359600, "currency"=>"USD", "firstrecorded_at"=>1382359600, "availability"=>"Available", "price"=>"36.60", "id"=>"39GVaekhIuOyAeyOyiKkCc"}, {"seller"=>"Colamco", "lastrecorded_at"=>1379825800, "firstrecorded_at"=>1379825800, "currency"=>"USD", "availability"=>"Available", "id"=>"05CmUv60bxIQiumM0mWgUe", "price"=>"34.27"}]

Comment: What trouble are you having?  What is going wrong with your JSON parsing?  Does the code you put up there crash?  Not show expected results?  What are you expecting?

Comment: The code returns the entire hash.  I have tried using the json gem to parse the data with JSON.parse(@productsHash) but not sure how to extract the data I need.

Comment: You're asking how to access parsed JSON?

Comment: yes and wondering if anyone has used this api specifically

Comment: Accessing the JSON values will be the same regardless of API, it's only the nesting and structure that will change.

Comment: `JSON.parse`, you seem to have it covered.  There's a reason "Be Specific" is a heading on [the how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  We're not sure how to help you because you don't seem to have a problem.

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks for the tips.
my view
`<% @productsHash['results'].each do |sitedetails| %>
          <% @data << sitedetails['sitedetails'] %>
      <% end %>
      <% @data.each do |latestoffers| %>
          <% if latestoffers %>
              <% latestoffer = latestoffers.first['latestoffers'].first %>
              <%= latestoffer['seller'] + ' : ' + number_to_currency(latestoffer['price']) %>
              <hr>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop @productshash as it is an array of hashes and use the particular key for which you want to get value associated with

In you rails controller just use this code

```
sem3.products_field("search", "green toys tractor")
sem3.products_field( "sitedetails", "name")


# Make the query

productsHash = sem3.get_products()
@products = productsHash["results"]
```

in the view just loop the @product

```
<% @products.each do |prod| %>
<%= "Product name: #{prod["name"]}"%>
#You can use as many as fields you want
<%end%>
```